# How do you save a PDF with FDPF using parameters?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdf, fpdf

I have this button, that is tied to this function:

```
$('#genPDF').click(function () {

    var str = "hText=something" +
        "&cText=also something";

    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/indexpdf.php",
        data: str,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("Success!");
            $("#pdfobject").attr("src", "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/flyer.pdf");
            var container = document.getElementById("pdfContainer");
            var content = container.innerHTML;
            container.innerHTML = content;
        }
    });
});
```

To explain what the successful ajax code does, first outputs "success!" in the console, which the browser does, then replaces a certain div on the page with a revised link (refreshing a certain part of the page).

This above code works, and makes it's way over to indexpdf.php, which is:

```
<?php

    $hText = trim(isset($_GET['hText']) ? $_GET['hText'] : '');
    $cText = trim(isset($_GET['cText']) ? $_GET['cText'] : '');

    require_once('fpdf.php');
    require_once('fpdi.php');

    // initiate FPDI
    $pdf = new FPDI();

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->setSourceFile("TestFlyer.pdf");

    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);

    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
    $pdf->Write(0, $hText.$cText);

    $pdf->Output("D","flyer.pdf");
?>
```

The problem is, it's supposed to take testflyer.pdf, load it's first page and write my passed in arguments into it. THEN, save itself as flyer.pdf.

It's not saving, I don't know what's doing on or what the problem is.

All PDF's and PHP files above are in the /mytheme/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the PDF, set the dest parameter as F:
So,

```
 $pdf->Output("D","flyer.pdf");
```

must be:

```
 $pdf->Output("F","flyer.pdf");
```

And reformat your write line as:

```
$pdf->Write(0, "$hText $cText");
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/), destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:

```
I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
S: return the document as a string.
```

The default value is I.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can help me with another question? How would you go about loading a PDF, then producing another PDF with generated text and write that PDF on top of the other PDF

Comment: Post another question on it.

Comment: here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752092/how-to-overlay-write-on-top-of-existing-pdf-with-html-generated-pdf

Comment: hoping you can help!