# Is it possible to use PDF as HTML page background in CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dompdf

Is there a way to set a PDF as a background for an HTML file? It needs to be compliant to CSS v2.1. I'm looking to doing something like this in the html page:

```
body {
     background-image: url(FULLURL/myPDF.pdf);
}
```

The main purpose behind this is to to basically render an HTML as a PDF, overlaying an already existing PDF. (This I'm doing with PHP and resources like DOMPDF)

The reason it was to be CSS v2.1 compliant, is because the resource is set that way: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Anyone have any ideas? I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Why not just convert it to an image?

Comment: @ceejayoz Would've gone that way, but I didn't want to lose any quality and have it pixelated. I found a way to do this :) , but using a PHP resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting it as a background, no, not possible. You may be able to get away with an [ugly hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593176/div-layer-on-top-of-pdf), but... I think you need to rethink what you're trying to accomplish and find an alternative solution.

PDF is a proprietary format and therefore does not play well with open web languages.

Comment: If this is unlikely to work, do you think you could aid me with my original question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752092/how-to-overlay-write-on-top-of-existing-pdf-with-html-generated-pdf

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda the answer to your original question is that it's not possible.

Comment: Are you talking about the link I just posted as a response? or did you think I meant this question?

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda both, it is not possible to set PDF as a background in CSS, nor is it possible to overlay HTML on top of it.

Comment: My original question is more along the lines of "can I overlay a pdf on top of a pdf" one of which is an HTML rendered pdf.

Comment: Also, I understand I can't set a PDF as a background. it's a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Background not an option as far as I know. But refer [embed pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) to view a pdf on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the original question: it *is* possible and it's actually pretty annoying! It leaves a whole white block on the webpage before the actual content; it can be viewed by right clicking View Background Image...

It looks like (incorrect URL):